# Bigcommerce getOrders() timeout line 198 (parseHeader?)

Tags: php, curl, bigcommerce

Afternoon,

Just taking a look at the bigcommerce API and I am stuck very early on! I am using PHP not curl as its on a windows machine its much easier and would like it to be available on shared hosting etc...

So I am using the bigcommmerce.php

My current file looks like this

```
Bigcommerce::configure(array(
'store_url' => '******',
'username' => 'demo',
'api_key' => '******'
));
Bigcommerce::setCipher('RC4-SHA');
Bigcommerce::verifyPeer(false);

$count = Bigcommerce::getOrdersCount()/200;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i) {
    $filter = array('limit' => 200, 'page' => $i);
    $orders = Bigcommerce::getOrders($filter);
    foreach($orders as $order) {
        echo $order->name;
        echo $order->price;
    }
 }
```

I have tested the connection with the ping request which works fine.
Also it can retrieve number of orders fine (the GetOrderCount part) however when I try to retrieve the orders I get a timeout.

You can see the output at this link (will take 300 seconds to timeout)

http://www.32bytes.co.uk/test/test.php

Its refering to like 198 being the problem line which is this chunk of code(function)....

```
private function parseHeader($curl, $headers)
{
    if (!$this->responseStatusLine && strpos($headers, 'HTTP/') === 0) {
        $this->responseStatusLine = $headers;
    } else {
        $parts = explode(': ', $headers);
        if (isset($parts[1])) {
            $this->responseHeaders[$parts[0]] = trim($parts[1]);
        }
    }
    return strlen($headers);
```

The bigcommerce.php page is left as default direct from themselves.

Any help would be much appreciate - Cant see where I am going wrong!

Comment: Please post the exact error and which line is line 198.

Comment: for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i) -- is this is a mistake or you meant $i++?

Comment: @DanielPaulSearles The second code block is line 198. That whole file is this one .. https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php/blob/master/bigcommerce.php

Comment: @apoq I have tried adding ++ but still no luck with it working

Comment: @DanielPaulSearles The error after 300 seconds is... 'Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\SitesDirectory\32Bytes\test\bigcommerce.php on line 193'

Comment: @apoq is correct in suggesting you add a `++` to your for loop. Currently you have an infinite loop since you don't increment the `$i` variable nor do you `break` from the outer for loop.

Comment: you have tried adding ++, but still it doesnt work, so you remove it again? what exactly do you expect in this loop?

Answer (score 1):

It just takes too long for your script to fetch all the order pages.
You can "fix" it by cancelling auto execution timeout setting by adding the following to the top of your script file/bootstrap:

```
ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', -1);
```

Comment: Had tried this previously, I have re-uploaded it to... http://www.32bytes.co.uk/test/getorders.php It has been running 30 mins still not returned anything, is this normal? Any program that can diagnose its progress and I could see it working? Currently i am just running it on live PHP scripts, many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Matt can you write here the values you have $count, and $orders?

Answer (score 1):

I too used php to fully access bigCommerce for in order to keep my in-house inventory application up-to-date.

i am using only

```
$orders = BigCommerce_Api::getCollection('/orders/');
```

and then iterating that in a foeach loop

```
foreach($orders as $order) { .... print to page or db, which ever you choose }
```